# How to remove item and replace it with a new one at the same place in ArrayList?

Tags: kotlin

I have ArrayList for example:

`var list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("one", "two", "three")`

And I need to replace `"two"` with `"four"`, so I need to delete it and replace at the same place with `"four"` but i don't know where is `"two"` is located. How can i do that?

Comment: Problem solved: `list[list.indexOf("two")] = "four"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the most simple form:

```
val list = arrayListOf("one", "two", "three")

// get the index of the item to swap
val index = list.indexOf("two")

// set the item at index to the new value
list[index] = "four"

// result is ["one", "four", "three"]
```

You may want to check if the list actually contains the value, by asserting that `index >= 0`

Answer (score 3):

The simpler way is finding the index of the element you want to replace and the set the new value for it as follows:

```kotlin
var list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("one", "two", "three")
int index = list.indexOf("two");
list.set(index, "four");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.replace(old: T, new: T) = map { if (it == old) new else it }
```

Usage: `list.replace("two", "four")`

Comment: This creates and returns a copy of the list. You could use [replaceAll](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/replace-all.html#replaceall) to modify the original list if desired.